# How do I access the properties of this JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting data from a simple API (http://data.police.uk).

I get the data with getJSON:

```
var police = $.getJSON(queryurl);
```

A console.log on `police` shows this:

[image: Console screenshot]

But I can't seem to access the properties in the object.

I assumed I could access it with, for example, `police.responseJSON`, but this comes back as undefined.

I know there are a few similar questions on this already, but none of the answers seem to help my specific situation. For example I've also tried `police[0].responseJSON` and `police['responseJSON']` but both are undefined.

Comment: You're not using `$.getJSON` right - you need a success hander of some kind. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Out of interest (I'm relatively new to the site), why the -1? I assume it's because I've misunderstood how getJSON works? But is lack of knowledge reason to downvote, or can I improve the question in some way? (Genuine question).

Comment: More likely because looking in manual would have answered your own problem

Comment: @DizzyEgg - Yeah, charlieftl is right, I downvoted because the question could have easily been answered by reading the documentation (it's the first example on the page I linked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid because if you try to assign $.getJSON to a variable, you assign the constructor of the .getJSON() method, not a return value.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON(queryurl, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

$.getJSON() will automatically parse the json response text to an object literal. So you can use `data.age_range` to access the values easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON(queryURL, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

You need to use either a success callback or the Promise interface.